# How does adding tags change a text file - Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tags

I am a beginner in Tkinter and I am currently trying to create an interface, which runs a program which checks for the 'correctness' of formal specifications. What this program does is checks whether a written specification meets certain criteria - checks whether all terms used are declared, etc.

Anyway, I am trying to add a search button, which changes the color of a key words, when they are found in the text - I use tags and it works ok. The problem is, after I have used my search function (i.e. have added tags and then removed them, when clicking on save) the program which checks for the 'correctness' of the specification doesn't run properly, even on files which have been checked and shown correct. I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1193, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
TclError: invalid command name ".43965456"
```

I have no idea what this might mean. I was just wondering whether adding tags changes a text file in some way (apart from changing the color of key words), which might mess up with the program, which checks for 'correctness'.

Here is my Search function:

```
def searchWindowButton(self,event):

        self.top = Toplevel()
        self.top.title("Search")
        Label(self.top,text='Text to find:').pack(side=LEFT)
        self.edit = Entry(self.top)
        self.edit.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.edit.focus_set()
        button = Button(self.top, text="Search", command = self.on_button)
        button.pack(side=LEFT)


    def find(self):

        self.txt.tag_remove('found', '1.0', END)
        s = self.edit.get()
        if s:
            idx = '1.0'
            while 1:
                idx = self.txt.search(s, idx, nocase=1, stopindex=END)
                if not idx: break
                lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len(s))
                self.txt.tag_add('found', idx, lastidx)
                idx = lastidx
            self.txt.tag_config('found', background='green', foreground='black')
        self.edit.focus_set()


    def on_button(self):
        self.find()
        self.top.destroy()
```

And this is my Save function:

```
def saveMenu(self):
        try:
            self.txt.tag_remove("found",  "1.0", 'end')
            fileName=self.fl
            fl = open(fileName, 'w')
            textoutput = self.txt.get(0.0, END)
            fl.write(textoutput)
        except:
            self.save_asMenu()
```

Comment: Please post a complete minimal example. IMHO you are overwriting an already defined variable.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you asked for - the whole program is quite long, I am not sure how much of it would be useful. Let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, `0.0` is not a valid text index. It works as a side-effect of the tkinter implementation, but the very first character of the widget has an index of `"1.0"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was just wondering whether adding tags changes a text file in some
>   way (apart from changing the color of key words)

No, adding tags has absolutely zero effect on a text file.

`TclError: invalid command name ".43965456"` means that a widget with the internal id of .43965456 has been destroyed prior to you calling whatever function triggers the error.